# Synchronize tables with mismatched columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following situation:

In my database: `Table "Items"  => Several thousand records, 35 columns`.
Linked server: `View "ItemInfo" => Several thousand records, 45 columns`.

1 column in both ("ItemID") provides the matching key between table and view `(Unique, not NULL in both.)`

30 columns (not counting ItemID) appear on both sides, but may be of different type. *E.g*, in view `ItemInfo` it is a date or number field, while in table `Items` has a string containing a date or number. This happens on about half of the columns.

Table and view content do not exactly match. 
About 99% of the rows appear in both with matching `ItemID` (but the other columns may have different values). The other 1% only appears on one side.

I need a stored procedure (in the database containing table `Items`) to update the table `Items`, so that that values from the view `ItemInfo` are copied in the table.  (For a matching row the values from the view are leading.)

**Additionally:** In case a rows doesn't exist in table `Items`, it must be copied from view `ItemInfo`. Extras in the table (not present in the view) can be left as is.

I need to synchronize the table with the view several times a day, but the number of mutations (each synchronization) will be very low. Possibly none. I have no way to tell if a entry in the view is actually "new" or "updated".

My current proposed solution is to do this in 2 steps:

1. for rows in view `ItemInfo` that have no match in table `Items` insert that row in table `Items`, using a sub-expression for each column (if needed) to do type-conversion.
2. run an update over table `Items` updating each column (with a sub-expression) with the corresponding value from the matching entry (if existing) from view `ItemInfo`.

Step 2 is obviously very in-efficient, because there is no need to update the vast majority of the rows. 
Only a handful (if any) will actually have been changed since the last update.

The whole thing involves a bloody mess of sub-expressions, but I don't see any other approach.
Can someone think of a better idea to implement something like this?

*To clarify:

I'm not looking for an complete solution to my problem, but more for a general approach to take on similar problems.

I'm certain I'm going to face this multiple times over the coming years...*

**P.S.**
I have no control over the view. Just read-only access to read it. I do have full control of the database where table is located, but I can't change anything about the structure of table `Items` itself, because there is other software interfacing with this table over which I have no control. I'm free to add temporary tables if needed.

Comment: There is entirely too much text and far too little technical information here. It is more like a chapter out of a book then a technical question. What doesn't make sense it you have a view and a table that are out of synch???? Views are only stored queries, they do not contain any actual data. That means that there is something else wrong here.

Comment: Do you happen to be lucky enough to have last updated timestamps on your view and table?

Comment: @SeanLange I'm forced to deal with existing applications and their databases. Owned and operated by different divisions of the company. I completely agree this sucks. But I'm not in a position to change it. I have to live with it.

Comment: @Becuzz I'm afraid not. There are some timestamps but these don't relate to anything useful in the context of this synchronization. (E.g. "Procurement date" and "End of warranty".) If I had a timestamp related to last status-change it would  have been quite easy. Only need to check the records where that timestamp is later than the time of last synchronization. Still just as much work to write the update, but at least no need for unnecessary updates.

Comment: I understand being forced to plug our noses and plow forward even when something is less than ideal. However, in this case it is not clear what the problem is. How can you have a view for ItemInfo that doesn't have a row in Items?? Remember we can't see your screen and have no idea what your system is doing or what the tables are like.

Comment: @SeanLange It sounds to me like the view exists on a separate server / database than the items table he needs to update.  Thus his view isn't pulling from the items table he needs to sync.

Comment: Why not combine steps 1 and 2 so that your insert already has the values needed from the view?